# Find all natural numbers $k \geq 4$ such that $ k|2(k-3)! +36 $.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, factorial

Find all natural numbers $k \geq 4$ such that,
$$
k|2(k-3)! +36\,.
$$

Comment: You should try reducing to the cases where you will know that $k|2(k-3)!$ or $\lnot(k |2(k-3)!)$

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know Wilson's theorem?

Comment: Hint: If $k$ is a composite number $> 4$, show that $k\mid 2(k-3)!$.  If $k$ is a prime $\ge 4$, show that $2(k-3)!\equiv (k-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{k}$.

Comment: Is that $(k-3)!2$ or $(2k-6)!$?

Answer (score 3):

Either $k$ is prime or $k$ is composite.

*If $k$ is composite*

Then $k=4$ fails by trial and for all other possibilities ($k\ge6$) the factorial $(k-3)!$ includes factors of both $d$ and $k/d$ for some divisor $d$ of $k$.  Thus $k\ge 6$ and $k$ composite will satisfy the divisibility requirement iff $k|36$ admitting the solutions $k\in\{6,9,12,18,36\}$.

*If $k$ is prime*

Wilson's Theorem forces $(k-1)!\equiv -1\bmod k$.  Divide by $(k-1)(k-2)\equiv 2$ and multiply by $2$ to render

$2(k-3)!\equiv -1\bmod k$

This means the right hand side of the divisibility relation is $\equiv 35$ and prime solutions for $k$ must be factors of that number.  Thus prime values of $k$ are $\in\{5,7\}$.

The complete solution set is therefore $\{5,6,7,9,12,18,36\}$.